# Script filling password from command line

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, openssl

I have this command that I am calling from `php (exec())`:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out cred.p12
```

and then I need to insert password twice

```
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
```

I need script that will fill the password inputs, because `exec()` will only do that command, but not insert password twice. Do you have any idea how should I do it?

Comment: openssl has options to provide the password in the command, which are far easier to use.

Comment: openssl -passin argument will do this. e.g. openssl rsa -in key.pem -passin pass:secretpassword -text. For other ways to pass password to openssl check 'man openssl' PASS PHRASE section

Comment: Passing the password on the command line can expose it to e.g. anyone who runs `ps` at the right moment.

Answer (score 2):

A true bi-directional shell is not easy in php, but in this case you can just use a newline to simulate an enter press.

`exec("Command\nPassword\nPassword");`

For a true bi-directional (read & write) possibility you will need to look at `proc_open()`.
If you do not need the return output you can use the far easier `popen()` in `w` mode, but you'll need to verify that your command has successfully run because you won't get output or error codes back.